# Outlook 2013 Shared Calendar Not Auto Populating Data

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar

On a client's computer, when I open Outlook 2013 initially there's nothing showing up on the calendar.

However if I toggle to a different view on the calendar, everything populates.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I thought this was the answer. Account settings, change, more settings, advanced, and unchecking the "download shared folders". The 1st time I re-opened Outlook all appeared to be well. I restarted again and I was back to the same problem.

Comment: I've also tried taking it off cached exchange mode. Same thing happens. The 1st time I open Outlook "presto" the data in the calendar populates, but if I re-open yet again, the problem of no data populating reoccurs.

Comment: Thinking it might possibly be an issue with his video card. Downloaded the latest driver. As well, installing the latest Windows updates. Crossing fingers!

Comment: Alas, haven't gotten anywhere. I rebuilt their Outlook profile and still no joy.

Comment: I still haven't gotten anywhere with this one. Anyone experienced this?